Speed control fan with PWM and capacitor (no pwm fan)
For my project I want to control the speed of a regular non-PWM fan.
I was wondering if what I came out with is a good idea or not. I noticed that the capacitor I used (25V 47µF) gets a bit warm after a while, when setting pwm <90%, what looks not good to me for an electrolytic capacitor.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Does maybe some reverse current from the fan makes the capacitor warm? Is the way i want to regulate the fan recommended at all? Problem is, i have no other pins left for using a real pwm pin, so this is the only route i could go.
Thanks in advance!

C1 is being hammered by M1 the low on resistance mosfet turning on .Most DC fans have a cap inside them which can die on PWM .Really it is best to give the fan a variable well filtered DC voltage for reliability. This means inductance and capacitance and using a faster part for D1             .You should run much much higher Arduino pwm freq to keep L and C not to big .If you must persist with the 220 Hz and dont want a big coil you could slow down the turn on of N1 to reduce peak currents  cooling C1 and warming M1

Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately i havent understood most of your last sentence - I have no clue what N1 should be :D
But when I understood you correct, it would be better for my usecase to implement a simple buck converter circuit. The reason why i have chosen 220Hz was, that this was the frequency which was less annoying, because the fan makes noise when driving it with the circuit shown above
